# Show that $m! (n − m)!$ divides $n!$ for all $m$, $n \in \Bbb{N}$ with $m \leq n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I am studying Analysis by Amann and Escher by my own I am stuck at this exercise:

Show that $m! (n − m)!$ divides $n!$ for all $m$, $n\in\Bbb{N}$ with $m\leq n$.
(Hint: $(n+1)!=n!(n+1−m)+n!m$.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: $n!=m!(m+1)(m+2)\cdots n.$

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the hint, use induction. It is trivial to check that the statement is true for $n=1$. Suppose it is true for $n$ and for every $m\leq n$.
Now suppose $m\leq n+1$. Then
\[
\frac{(n+1)!}{m!(n+1-m)!}=\frac{n!(n+1-m)+n!m}{m!(n+1-m)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}+\frac{n!}{(m-1)!(n+1-m)!}
\]
By the induction hypothesis each term on the right hand side is an integer, so we are done.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, I want to use the hint to prove by induction not by using binomial coefficient as you did.

Comment: I think the first two denominators should be $m!(n+1-m)!$ (there's a missing factorial "$!$" in your answer).

Comment: @HaiderAtrah The solution has nothing to do with binomial coefficients. He/she claims $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}$ to be an integer due to induction hypothesis, not out of similarity to $\binom{n}{m}$.

Comment: Babak comments clears the confusion. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

A combinatorial-like proof (fill in details): the number of subsets with $\;m\;$ elements of a set with $\;n\;$ elements, $\;n\ge m\;$ , is given by

$$\binom nm:=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$

As the above number is always an integer, the claim follows.

If you want a more algebraic proof, just play a little with the above expression and read carefully Alex's comment.

Comment: Actually the book mentions the above binomial coefficient but only after the above mentioned question, so it seems the authors asking for a proof by induction. I tried to play with hint given but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take any prime number $p$ and observe that within 
$$1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot k$$
it is used exactly
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^2} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^3} \right\rfloor
+\ldots
$$ times (this series becomes zero after $\log_p k$ steps).

So to prove your theorem we need to show that

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^3} \right\rfloor
+\ldots
\geq 
\left\lfloor \frac{m}{p} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m}{p^2} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m}{p^3} \right\rfloor
+\ldots
+
\left\lfloor \frac{n-m}{p} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{n-m}{p^2} \right\rfloor
+\ldots
$$
which is easy to see when split into multiple similar parts:
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \right\rfloor
  = \left\lfloor\frac{m}{p^i}+\frac{n-m}{p^i}\right\rfloor
  \geq \left\lfloor \frac{m}{p^i} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n-m}{p^i} \right\rfloor$$
because $\lfloor a+b\rfloor \geq \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor$ for any real numbers $a$ and $b$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$